# How to edit ajax requests online

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, web-scraping, request

I want to scrape all products from my amazon associate but the page just loads 20 product per scroll and to show more I need to scroll, it uses infinity scroll, so scrape all products will take much time to load all products

there is any way to show all products to be available in DOM and be able to scrape them without scroll to show 20 product per scroll